# .htaccess redirect index.php but 404 if without .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so the thing is that if i write 'localhost/mvc/' or 'localhost/mvc/index.php' it works fine but if i type 'localhost/mvc/index' it returns a 404 not found. The requested URL /mvc/index was not found on this server.

> .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

in my root mvc there is only a few subdirs, .htaccess and index.php

Answer (score 1):

To remove .php extension use following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For .html extension Rewrite Rule will be

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```